# How to multiply certain columns/fields in a large array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance, loops

I have an array as the following:

```
const data = [
  { Date: "2012", A: 2,   B: 3,   C: 4 },
  { Date: "2013", A: 4,   B: 7,   C: 8 },
  { Date: "2014", A: 0.1, B: 0.3, C: 0.4 },
];
```

I want to multiply specific columns/fields by `100`, so I created a new array that holds their keys:

```
const arr = ["A", "B", "C"];
```

And then I use `.map` to multiple those columns:

```
arr.forEach((element, i) => data.map(a => a[element] * 100));
```

However, when I check the `data` array of objects it seems to be unchanged:

```js
const data = [
  { Date: "2012", A: 2,   B: 3,   C: 4 },
  { Date: "2013", A: 4,   B: 7,   C: 8 },
  { Date: "2014", A: 0.1, B: 0.3, C: 0.4 },
];

const arr = ["A", "B", "C"];

arr.forEach((element, i) => data.map(a => a[element] * 100));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the new values.

If you want to mutate the original elements, then instead of `a[element] * 100` you should have `a[element] = a[element] * 100` or `a[element] *= 100`.

If you don't want to mutate the original elements, then you should be assigning back the value `map` returns and creating new objects:

```
arr.forEach((element, i) => data = data.map(a => { 
  return { ...a, [element]: a[element] * 100 };
}));
```

If you are concerned about performance, you can use [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) to check how much time it takes to run different variations of your code:

```js
const columns = ["A", "B", "C"];

let data1 = [];
const data2 = [];
let data3 = [];
const data4 = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  data1.push({ Date: "2012", A: 2, B: 3, C: 4 });
  data2.push({ Date: "2012", A: 2, B: 3, C: 4 });
  data3.push({ Date: "2012", A: 2, B: 3, C: 4 });
  data4.push({ Date: "2012", A: 2, B: 3, C: 4 });
}

// Original code with map (doesn't mutate original rows):

const t1 = performance.now();

columns.forEach(column => data1 = data1.map(row => { 
  return { ...row, [column]: row[column] * 100 };
}));

console.log(Object.values(data1[0]).join(', '), performance.now() - t1);

// Original code with assignment (no map, mutates original rows):

const t2 = performance.now();

columns.forEach(column => data2.forEach(row => row[column] *= 100));

console.log(Object.values(data2[0]).join(', '), performance.now() - t2);

// Iteraring rows first with map (doesn't mutate original rows):

const t3 = performance.now();

data3 = data3.map((row, i) => {
  const newRow = { ...row };
  
  columns.forEach(column => newRow[column] *= 100);
  
  return newRow;
});

console.log(Object.values(data3[0]).join(', '), performance.now() - t3);

// Iteraring rows first with assignment (no map, mutates original rows):

const t4 = performance.now();

data4.forEach((row, i) => columns.forEach(column => row[column] *= 100));

console.log(Object.values(data4[0]).join(', '), performance.now() - t4);
```

Also, you might want to consider using a `for` or `while` loop, which might be faster than `.map` or `.forEach`.

Comment: I see you are not using `map` at all. Does this affect performance though? My real `data` array is quite large say thousand to tens of thousands objects in it.

Comment: Well, mutating the elements is actually faster than using `.map` and creating new ones. I have added different variations of your algorithm so that you can see the different amount of time it takes to run each of them. Also, if you are concerned about performance, consider using a simple `for` loop rather than `.map` or `.forEach`.

Comment: It looks like the original one is the fastest among these 4, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine `map` and `reduce` to create new array of objects and keep the original data.

```js
var data = [{Date:"2012", A:2, B:3, C:4}, {Date:"2013", A:4, B:7, C:8},  {Date:"2014", A:0.1, B:0.3, C:0.4}]
var arr = ["A","B","C"]

// map over data array and return a new object for each element
const result = data.map(o => ({
  // spread current object from original array
  ...o,
  // spread object returned from reduce that will overide original properties
  ...arr.reduce((r, k) => {
  // check if the current key ('A', 'B'...) exists in current object
  // and if it does create new property where the value is
  // original value * 100
    if (o[k]) r[k] = o[k] * 100;
  // return accumulator of reduce
    return r;
  }, {})
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop through the `data`, then for each obj, alter each `arr` key

```js
let data = [{Date:"2012", A:2, B:3, C:4}, {Date:"2013", A:4, B:7, C:8},  {Date:"2014", A:0.1, B:0.3, C:0.4}]
var arr = ["A","B","C"]

data.forEach((obj) => arr.forEach((a) => obj[a] *= 100));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

map returns a new array, it doesn't mutate the original array it iterates over.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` returns a new array, it won't mutate in place.

You could do this:

```
 arr.forEach((element, i) => data.forEach((a,i)=>data[i].a[element]*100))
```

... but I wouldn't recommend it.

Mutating an object that you're iterating over is a Bad Idea, much better to map into a new array.

Comment: Is it possible to mutate in place then?

Comment: well you're mutating the objects *within* the array, not the array itself... so yeah, it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the map function creates a new Array.
if you grab the output you will see that it is calculated and put into a new array (just with the output variables)

```
var data = [{Date:"2012", A:2, B:3, C:4}, {Date:"2013", A:4, B:7, C:8},  {Date:"2014", A:0.1, B:0.3, C:0.4}]
var arr = ["A","B","C"]
arr.forEach((element, i) =>  {
  var output = data.map(a=>a[element]*100)
  console.log(output);
}
)
```

OUTPUTS

```
[200, 400, 10]
[300, 700, 30]
[400, 800, 40]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ksL3pn0/

Answer (score -1):

It should be like this:

`arr.forEach((element, i) => data.map(a=>{a[element]*=100}))`